# HTML PHP onclick only working once

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Okay, here we go. I have an image that is clickable (ingenious, right?):

```
<DIV id="<?PHP echo($row[number]); ?>">                                                                                         
    <IMG TITLE="Favorite!" src="drool_bw_nobg.png" 
    align="center" onclick = "favorite(<?PHP echo($row[number]); ?>)"> &nbsp;
      <b>Like</b>
</DIV>
```

Keep in mind, I have already done this with PHP inline (example above), and done it with
an `echo()` statement, and even a `printf()` statement with the `\'%s\'` wildcard.

Okay, when I click the image, the `Favorite(id)` javascript function is called. The VERY first command is an `alert();` statement, followed by some AJAX code.

The latter works perfectly, and the php script that the AJAX references does its job very well when the image on the main page is clicked.

Then you can go onto click other images too, and the everything still works perfectly, but you click an image you have already clicked on...nothing...nada...zilch. The `alert()` statement doesn't even pop up.

A real head scratcher. Hopefully someone has had this problem before, and found a clever solution.

Here is my favorite() javascript function:

```
function favorite(id){
  alert(id);
  getImage = document.getElementById(id);
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?img="+id,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

As I said, everything works the first time, but you have to refresh the page before you can click the same image again.

Comment: Can you show us your `favorite` function?

Comment: The `$row['number']` variables aren't all the same, are they?

Comment: My favorite function is `console.log` :P

Comment: @CarlMarkham Have you discovered `console.dir`?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but I prefer using expression blocks: `<?=$row[number] ?>` instead of `<?php echo($row[number]); ?>`

Comment: Do you try to check `console` if anything display ?
Maybe browser lock popup when you alert many times ( just suggestion )

Comment: expression blocks? Your example <?=$row[number] ?> is an echo statement? Sweet! I will definitely use that.

Comment: @fanfan1609  That is not my problem at all, because if I click another image, the popup still popsup, just never the same image.

Comment: @MarkGabriel  Yes, each image (there are over 1000, paginated). See, it is a picture blog, and I want to add a "LIKE" button. When I click the "LIKE" button, it likes it, and the PHP file that AJAX references adds to a MYSQL table...when I refresh the page, and click the "LIKE" image for the same image, it removes the record from the table.

Comment: Just a heads up, the uppercase HTML is pretty unconventional now

Comment: `<?=$row[number] ?>` would only work if `short_open_tags` is enabled on the server.

Comment: @mowwwalker  Yeah, I know the uppercase is unconventional now, it just makes it all easier to read to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here's the issue. You have this content (I've removed all irrelevant tags/attributes/PHP):

```
<DIV id="1">
    <IMG onclick="favorite(1);"/>
</DIV>
```

When you click on the `IMG`, the `favorite()` function gets called. You then get your contents via AJAX, and update the `innerHTML` of the `DIV` element. At this point, you're replacing the `DIV` contents with the contents you retrieve from your AJAX request.

Most likely, the AJAX contents do not contain the `onclick` handler, so once you've updated the element once, your `onclick` handler is gone. Subsequent clicks will no longer call your `favorite()` method.

Just put the `onclick` handler on your `DIV` instead of your `IMG`, and everything will be fine.

Comment: Or, don't put `onclick` anywhere and register event handlers separately from the HTML.

Comment: OMG, I cannot believe I didn't catch that. Thank you so much for that. Now, how on Earth would I register the event handlers and still pass the image number? to the javascript function?  Thanks again man.

Comment: Loop over the elements you need, get their IDs, attach an event handler to each element, and pass the ID to the handling function.